# C simple question of getting average value from array each components addition

Tags: c, average

This is a c code for getting the average value of the addition of array components.
But once I run this which is not outputting anything.

Can anyone help me out where I got the code wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double solution(int arr[], size_t arr_len);

int main()

{
    int array[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int length = sizeof(array[10]);
    double out = solution(array, length);
    printf("solution is %f\n", out);
    return 0;

}

double solution(int arr[], size_t arr_len) {
    
    double answer = 0;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_len;){

        total += arr[i];

    }
    answer = total / arr_len;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: If the program actually never exits, it would have been useful to mention that in the question.

Comment: Are you concerned about `int` overflow in summing the `int` array elements?  Use of `double` to sum leads to imprecision.

Comment: Wrong size: `int length = sizeof(array[10]);` --> `size_t length = sizeof array/sizeof *array;`

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the loop counter in `solution` so its stuck in an infinite loop.

`for (int i = 0; i < arr_len;){`

needs to be

`for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {`

Edit:

`sizeof` is also wrong. It returns the total memory used by the array. So you need to do

`int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`

which divides the total memory by the size of one element to give you the total number of elements.

Comment: And the array length is wrong anyway

Comment: Oh wow now it works! Thanks!!